# ı can save tasks but ı can't save color choice with shared preferences

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Im new flutter world. I trying to develop simple apps, ı think ım going well but ı have a simple problem in my to-do app. I can save my tasks with shared pref. but ı cant color choice. All stackoverflow's problems related my topic is "already visited" .  I try to save my colors ı write little weird code but its ok. if ı succsess ı will fix all. Thank you for your interest. when ı choice the color from list in settings page, and carrying the chosen color between page with callback.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7hPe.png)

```
   InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            for (var idx = 0; idx == 0; idx++) {
              setState(() {
                widget.selectedColor = colors[idx];
              });
            }
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 40,
            width: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

for all color ı have a for cycle to get index num. I can choose the color I want. And then in my main page, the color value I carry with callbacks ı try to save is good. color is carrying but when ı hot restart the incoming color disappears and takes its old color.

```
      class TasksScreen extends StatefulWidget {
        var color;
        TasksScreen(this.color);
        @override
        State<TasksScreen> createState() =>                           
          _TasksScreenState();
        final listKey = "list_key";
        }

     class _TasksScreenState extends State<TasksScreen> {
     @override
     void initState() {
       initSharedPrefernces();

       super.initState();
       }

    initSharedPrefernces() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setInt('color', widget.color.hashCode);
      prefs.getInt('color');
      Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false).loadData();

      setState(() {});
      }
```

ı already tried widget.color.value for prefs.setInt() but for this, my color variable is should be Color type. If ı make type of Color, ı have to assing a color. Color must be not null. But ı don't want to give a color to start. I can upload only 1 picture but all my page is like; ı have a button appbar action in my main page and the button go to settings page and my settings page have a 3 section. Color change setting is in Appearance section.

Comment: store color as String value in Shared Preferences

Comment: what do you mean? how can ı store colors as a String? also  "await prefs.setInt('color', widget.color.hashCode)" this code returning true. so its saved but why ı reopened the app color is change?

Comment: you are storing color as int how can you get true as a return value.

Comment: after final prefs = SharedPreferences.instance, prefs variable is giving you some methods. example; setInt, setString etc. this methods returning Future<bool> type. But this is not the point, this is not an answer to the question i asked. thanks. If you help me, ı'll thankful